# Планка ОЗУ не позволяет включиться компу

Tags: железо, пк

Суть: одним "прекрасным утром" стационарник [сокет 1150, intel i5]
просто отказался включаться. Постоянно перевожу его в сон и раньше всё было ок.
Выяснил, что при отсутствии одной планки ОЗУ 2*4Гб запускается нормально. Хотя память новенькая (м.б. 1 год, как поставил). Но 4Гб мне маловато, решил всё же воткнуть планку, но в другой слот. 
Всё заработало!
Пара дней ок, затем синий экран и та же беда с включением.
Переставил эту же планку обратно в старый слот - всё Ок...

WTF знатоки? Действительно ли проблема в планке или могут быть и другие причиы? 
Memtest проведу через пару дней

Comment: Может окисление? Стирательной резинкой пройдитесь по контактам. MEMTEST-ом проверяли память?

Comment: Есть ещё одна идея - планка вставлена плохо (например, защелки не до конца закрылись) или контакт от старости разболтался. В системнике есть вентилятор, который старенький и немного вибрирует. Также вполне может быть, что системник иногда получает "удары" ногой/рукой. И планка немного "вываливается". Переустановка собственно и исправляет эту проблему. Как вариант, предлагаю поменять планки местами. Если проблема будет воспроизводиться с планкой - проблема в ней. Если проблема будет с другой планкой - проблема в разъеме.

Comment: Старость и окислы исключаю т.к. обновил комп около года назад. На другом, которому уже лет 7 всё ок, без протирки, промывки, с постоянным дёрганьем внутренностей. Удары - тоже не, корпус даже на мягкой подстилке стоит для шумоподавления.
А поменять местами попробую при следующем падении системы!
Memtest проведу на днях и отпишусь

Comment: Хм. В субботу пересобрал свой ноутбук, почистив от пыли, и он тоже не включился. Обалдев, пересобрал ещё раз, безрезультатно. Поменял местами чипы оперативки -- включился. Списал на то, что плохо вставил .-.

Comment: если это был dell - то нормально. Там бывает нужно "правильно включить", что бы он запустил распознавание железа.